# At what point does a Process Builder process get triggered

Tags: apex, trigger, process-builder

I am using a large collection of Visual Processes (Lightning process builder) to execute APEX code, I am trying to avoid a race condition. So I am trying to figure out exactly at point does the process get triggered.

```
...
//Inserts Invoice__c
insert invoice;
...
insert invoiceLineItems;
//Code end
```

So if I have a process listening for the creation of Invoice__c, does it get triggered after the above transaction or does it get triggered at the insert process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes after the workflows are executed. Check out the following link [Apex Trigger order of Excution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm), **Execute Process** is #14 on the list.

In your case if you have a process flow when a invoice is created, it will be triggered before your insert the invoiceLineItems

Answer (score 0):

Also consider this [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=process_considerations_design.htm&language=en_US) for guidance specifically on Processes